# Trying to make a try catch continuously loop until service resumes

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, error-handling

I basically have a method that is checking a service constantly in a different thread. This works fine, but I need to make a check so that if the host closes, it keeps trying until service is resumed.

I thought this would work

```
private void GetTankLevels()
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.DieselBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DieselBox.Text = client.GetTankAmounts("Diesel").ToString(); }));
                    this.PetrolBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { PetrolBox.Text = client.GetTankAmounts("Unleaded").ToString(); }));
                    double DFuelLvl = client.GetTankAmounts("Diesel");
                    double PFuelLvl = client.GetTankAmounts("Unleaded");

                    int DieselProgress = (int)DFuelLvl;
                    int petrolProgress = (int)PFuelLvl;
                    if (DFuelLvl < 300)
                    {

                        this.DieselBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DieselBar.Value = DieselProgress; }));

                    }
                    else if (DFuelLvl > 300 && DFuelLvl < 500)
                    {
                        this.DieselBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DieselBar.Value = DieselProgress; }));

                    }
                    else if (DFuelLvl > 500 && DFuelLvl < 850)
                    {
                        this.DieselBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DieselBar.Value = DieselProgress; }));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.DieselBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DieselBar.Value = DieselProgress; }));

                    }

                    if (PFuelLvl < 300)
                    {
                        this.Petrolbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Petrolbar.Value = petrolProgress; }));

                    }
                    else if (PFuelLvl > 300 && PFuelLvl < 500)
                    {
                        this.Petrolbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Petrolbar.Value = petrolProgress; }));

                    }
                    else if (PFuelLvl > 500 && PFuelLvl < 850)
                    {
                        this.Petrolbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Petrolbar.Value = petrolProgress; }));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Petrolbar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Petrolbar.Value = petrolProgress; }));

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Lost connection to the host... Please wait");

                }

            }
        }
```

But it's being a bit unpredictable.
Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing your service from `Invoke()`, so the code gets executed not on your thread, but on main UI thread. And when exception is thrown there, it is not catched by your try/catch block.

You can move all service calls outside of Invoke, so that they will be executed on your thread.

Comment: Oh so pass the returned data from my  services in variables then  do the invokes out of the trycatch